# How can I retrieve user's general location through the Instagram API?

Tags: instagram, screen-scraping

I am working on a scraping project and I was wondering if I could get an account's follower locations through the API.

I am aware I could fetch through every follower's feed and snatch out its location, however, that could only be possible if they had its account public. I am expecting to get a list of followers and its general location